# How to compare and sort the variables that include the name of the teams and the chance of goals in percent

Tags: javascript

I have a few variables. The first variable always contains the name of the football club, and the next one – the chance of a goal as a percentage.

**Example:**

`a="Man City", b=45.55%, c="Barcelona", d=57.6%, e="Everton", f=38.53%;` etc.

I need to compare the chances of goal among all the teams, and sort them in descending order, with an indication of which team this or that chance belongs to.

When I use *alert()* command, I want that the output be similar to:

```
1.Barcelona: Chance 57.6%
2.Man City: Chance 45.55%
3.Everton: Chance 38.53%
```

Comment: What relates the team name variable with its respective chance of getting a goal? Are they contained in an object together, or maybe a parallel array? If they are all separate, there would be no way to tell which percentage corresponds to which team.

Comment: Initially, all these values were obtained by "Extract" command from iMacros. These are just sequential extracts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a more optimal way to do this, but here is the solution I used:

- Compose your given values into an Array
- Separate the values into 2 separate Arrays based on whether even or not
- Loop through one of the new arrays (assuming they are both the same length)
- Create an Array of Objects with keys of `city` and `chance`
- Sort the Array of Objects by `chance` value
- Loop through the Array of Objects to output the desired results (I simplified the output considerably from a production version)

```js
const a="Man City";
const b=45.55;
const c="Barcelona";
const d=57.6;
const e="Everton";
const f=38.53;

const vars = [a,b,c,d,e,f];
const city = [];
const chance = [];
const results = [];

vars.forEach((x,i) => {
  if (i % 2) {
    chance.push(x);
  } else {
    city.push(x);
  }
});

city.forEach((x,i) => {
  results.push({city: x, chance: chance[i]})
});

results.sort((a,b) => {
  if (a.chance > b.chance) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.chance < b.chance) {
   return 1;
  }
  
  return 0;
});

results.forEach((x,i) => {document.write(
(i + 1) + '. ' + x.city + ': Chance ' + x.chance + '%' + '<br>' 
)});
```

Answer (score 0):

This data would be better off structured as an array of objects, and your life will be much simpler with the javascript console (press F12 in your browser and in the pane that appears click "console"), such as:

```
var array = [
    {city: "Man City", chance: .4555},
    {city: "Barcelona", chance: .576},
    {city: "Everton", chance: .3853}
];

array.sort((a,b) => (a.chance < b.chance) ? 1 : ((b.chance < a.chance) ? -1 : 0));

for (var item of array) {
    console.log(item);
}
```

You'll still have to format chance as percent, and this would be more usable going into an element on the page, but this will give you a start.